# fontspec + package "accents" (bezos) = "! LaTeX Error: Command `\acute' already defined."

Tags: xetex, fontspec, accents

I am trying to define the "less-than" Symbol "<" as a math-accent via the "accents" package of Javier Bezos.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{accents}

\begin{document}

$\accentset{<}{A}$

\end{document}
```

However, I get the following error message:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command `\acute' already defined.
```

Leaving out the fontspec-package does the trick. Unfortunately, I need it for the rest of the document. Is there a way to get around this problem?

Comment: Interestingly, this looks very much like the errors I get with tex4ht and XeTeX... That'll have to go in another question though (if they persist with LuaTeX...)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It works with the `no-math` option for `fontspec`, which suppresses `fontspec` maths adjustments. This is also the behavior if a maths font package such as `mathpazo` or `unicode-math` is loaded, so the error would not occur then.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{accents}
\begin{document}
$\accentset{>}{A}$
\end{document}
```

[image: accent example]

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply; that solved the problem.