# make4ht and fontspec: lualatex not recognized?

Tags: fontspec, make4ht

I added `\usepackage{fontspec}` to my `.tex` file and the magic comment `% !TeX program = lualatex` in the preamble of my document.

Since I did so, I can no longer convert my document to `HTML` from a `.bat` script using `make4ht`. I receive the error message:

> htlatex: ?    45       Fatal Package fontspec Error: The fontspec package requires either XeTeX or LuaLaTeX

I read the question [after changing to \usepackage{fontspec} now make4ht do not compile my Latex file in lualatex mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317246/after-changing-to-usepackagefontspec-now-make4ht-do-not-compile-my-latex-file/317258#317258) and I still don't understand the problem. The answer to this question (from michal.h21) states that:

> Fontspec support have been just added to tex4ht, you can get it after TL update. Both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX are supported, although the implementation is different for both engines.

Why does `make4ht` not recognize the use of `LuaLaTex` despite the magic comment?

Comment: the comment is just that, a comment. It has no special status to tex. Some editors read comments in that form but the syntax varies from editor to editor. make4ht has commandline options to tell it to use luatex  `make4ht -l`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That solves my problem! If you want to post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: `make4ht` also supports these comments, but not by default. You can try `make4ht -f html5+detect_engine filename.tex`.

Comment: @michal.h21 ooh I added that to my answer so it's more visible than in comments, thanks,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't propagate this option too much, so it is no surprise that no one knows about it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment is just that, a comment. It has no special status to tex. Some editors read comments in that form but the syntax varies from editor to editor.

make4ht has a commandline option to tell it to use luatex: `make4ht -l`

make4ht also supports these comments, but not by default. You can try

```
make4ht -f html5+detect_engine filename.tex.
```